# How to increase the footnote line length in Arabic with scrbook?

Tags: footnotes, arabic, right-to-left, scrbook

If I write in English the code below would work, but when I write in Arabic it won't! I want to extend the length of the footnote line to the whole text width.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}
\setfootnoterule[1pt]{\textwidth} % default height is 0.4pt
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic} 

\begin{document}

هذه الحكاية حدثت في اوكرانيا\footnote{هي ثاني أكبر دول أوروبا الشرقية. يحدها الاتحاد الروسي من الشرق، بيلاروسيا من الشمال، بولندا وسلوفاكيا والمجر من الغرب، رومانيا ومولدوفا إلى الجنوب الغربي، والبحر الأسود وبحر آزوف إلى الجنوب}. 

\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic} 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{%
  \normalsize\ftn@rule@test@values
  \kern-\dimexpr 2.6\p@+\ftn@rule@height\relax
  \ifx\@textbottom\relax\else\vskip \z@ \@plus.05fil\fi
  {\usekomafont{footnoterule}{%
      \hrule \@height1pt \@width\textwidth}}%
  \kern 2.6\p@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

هذه الحكاية حدثت في اوكرانيا\footnote{هي ثاني أكبر دول أوروبا الشرقية. يحدها  الاتحاد الروسي من الشرق، بيلاروسيا من الشمال، بولندا وسلوفاكيا والمجر من الغرب، رومانيا ومولدوفا إلى الجنوب الغربي، والبحر الأسود وبحر آزوف إلى الجنوب}. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized there is a macro called `\textwidthfootnoterule` of `bidi` package that can be easily used to have the desired effect, given that the width of the `footnoterule` is set at default `0.4pt`, which now I prefer. The other answer is good to adjust width and length if needed. The `bidi` package will automatically be loaded by `polyglossia`.

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic}
\textwidthfootnoterule % of bidi package
\begin{document}

هذه الحكاية حدثت في اوكرانيا\footnote{هي ثاني أكبر دول أوروبا الشرقية. يحدها الاتحاد الروسي من الشرق، بيلاروسيا من الشمال، بولندا وسلوفاكيا والمجر من الغرب، رومانيا ومولدوفا إلى الجنوب الغربي، والبحر الأسود وبحر آزوف إلى الجنوب}.


\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want simply to make the rule appear to the right! If so, you should use the command `\rightfootnoterule`

```
[![\documentclass\[twoside=semi\]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage\[numerals=mashriq,abjadjimnotail=true\]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont\[Script=Arabic,Ligatures=TeX\]{Simplified Arabic}
\rightfootnoterule % Force footnote spearator rule to appear at right 
\begin{document}

هذه الحكاية حدثت في اوكرانيا\footnote{هي ثاني أكبر دول أوروبا الشرقية. يحدها الاتحاد الروسي من الشرق، بيلاروسيا من الشمال، بولندا وسلوفاكيا والمجر من الغرب، رومانيا ومولدوفا إلى الجنوب الغربي، والبحر الأسود وبحر آزوف إلى الجنوب}.


\end{document}][1]][1]
```

[image]